# SapUI5: Filter Value to databound value in Row Repeater

Tags: sapui5

I created a row repeater. The row repeater template consists of a panel which consists a table.

I have set a model for the row repeater and the tables uses that same model, but with a different path.

The model for the rows of the row repeater as a property LEVEL. Now I want to show in the tables for the rows only the values with the same level. So I tried tried to filter for that value like that:

```
oTemplateTable.bindRows({
        path: "/ROOT_COMPONENT",
        sorter: new sap.ui.model.Sorter("NAME"),
        filters: [new sap.ui.model.Filter(
            "LEVEL",
            sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "{LEVEL}")]
});
```

But this did not work. I need some way to get the level value for the row in which the table is in. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: How does your JSON response looks like, and can you show at which node your rowrepeater is bound, and at which childnode the table is bound?

Comment: The JSON response for ROOT_COMPONENT: {{NAME: "ABC", LEVEL: 1}, {NAME: "DEF", LEVEL: 2}}, for ROOT_STATISTICS: {{LEVEL: 1, AMOUNT: 20}, {LEVEL: 2, AMOUNT: 1}}. ROOT_STATISTICS is bound to the rowrepeater. The binding for the row repeater looks like that (oPanel is simply a panel that has the content oTemplateTable): oTemplateRowRepeater.bindRows(
            "/ROOT_STATISTIC",
            oTemplatePanel,
            new sap.ui.model.Sorter("LEVEL", false), [new sap.ui.model.Filter(
                "LEVEL",
                sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, -1)]);

Answer (score 0):

Both ROOT_COMPONENT and ROOT_STATISTICS are **objects** (i.e., `{{data},{data}}`) containing objects instead of **arrays** (i.e., `[{data}, {data}]`) containing objects, so I doubt you will be able to render the `RowRepeater` correctly

Furthermore, I think the `{LEVEL}` argument in your filter resolves back to ROOT_COMPONENT (since that's where you're binding your table to) and not ROOT_STATISTICS.

I think you could save yourself a lot of trouble if you could rework your JSON response to a more hierarchic one, so you won't need a filter anyway:

```
[{
    name      : "ABC",
    tableData : [
    {
        amount : 20
    }]
},
{
    name      : "DEF",
    tableData : [
    {
        amount : 1
    }]
}]
```

This way you just bind your rowrepeater to the root node, and your table to the relative child `tableData`

Comment: Oh sorry, i made the wrong notation. Of course they are Arrays of Objects. The problem i want to solve with this approach is that i have a list of templates which have different levels. i wanted to group the templates in different tables for each level. Therefor I have the ROOT_STATISTICS to know how many levels there are. I used the ROOT_STATISTICS in a row repeater to create different panels with tables (which works fine). I want so filter the tables with that level of root statistics. I don't think reworking the json response will solve the problem.